# Virtualisation on Raspberry Pi

Tags: server

For a project i am looking to run any kind if visualization software, on a couple of raspberry pi's. I know it's difficult because of ARM, but does anyone know software that is compatible? I could not find anything after googling for a while can someone help me?

Comment: Docker has been run on a Pi.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use

1) a type-1 hypervisor like [XVisor](http://xhypervisor.org/index.php?page=news/20151108)

or

2) QEMU on Linux KVM (sadly requiring a lot of preparation) :
http://blog.flexvdi.com/2015/03/17/enabling-kvm-virtualization-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/